# python is giving an error when trying to get tkinter entry value

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to print the tkinter entry value in python
like this.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def temperature():
    print(celciusEntry.get())

farenheidLabel = Label(root, text = "farenheid").place(x=110, y=10)
farenheidAnswer = Label(root, text="=",).place(x=110, y=30)

celciusLabel = Label(root, text="celcuis").place(x=20, y=10)
celciusEntry = Entry(root, width=10,).place(x=20, y=30)

temperaturebtn=Button(root, height=1, text="convert temperature", command=lambda:temperature())
temperaturebtn.place(x=20,y=100)

mainloop()
```

But I get a error saying `object has no attribute 'get'` why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
...
celciusEntry = Entry(root, width=10).place(x=20, y=30)
...
```

to

```
...
celciusEntry = Entry(root, width=10)
celciusEntry.place(x=20, y=30)
...
```